# Update multiple records simultaneously with ActiveRecord in Rails using one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, activerecord

Let's suppose I have a table called 'user_products' and a corresponding model called UserProduct in my Rails application. I also have a field called 'is_temporary' in my table. Now suppose I want to run a query like this but using the ActiveRecord abstraction layer:

```
UPDATE user_products SET is_temporary = false WHERE user_id = 12345;
```

Is there a way I can do this using ActiveRecord? Maybe something along the lines of

```
UserProduct.find_by_user_id(12345).update_attributes(:is_temporary => false)
```

I'd like only one query to be run for this to happen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
UserProduct.update_all({:is_temporary => false}, {:user_id => 12345})
```

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 19):

This is an old post. I updated this in case someone checks it :)  (Rails 4)

```
DEPRECATION: Relation#update_all with conditions is deprecated. Please use Item.where(color: 'red').update_all(...) rather than Item.update_all(..., color: 'red').
```

So the query will be

```
UserProduct.where(:user_id => 12345).update_all(:is_temporary => false)
```

Cheers

Comment: Is it possible to pass array in update_all, to make one to one corresponding update like. `UserProduct.where(:user_id => [1,2,3,4,5]).update_all(:name => ["ball", "bat", "shelf", "boots", "net"])`.

Answer (score 18):

```
UserProduct.update_all({:is_temporary => false}, {:user_id => 12345})
```

Although beware: this skips all validations and callbacks, since no instance of UserProduct will ever be instanciated.