# Rails mysql how to change time on mulitple columns at once?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my table I have a column dato that hold a datetime:

```
2011-04-12 10:37:07
2011-04-12 10:31:07
2011-04-10 10:32:07
2011-04-11 10:45:07
2011-04-12 10:37:07
```

I want to change all of the dato columns hour to 00:00:00

How is it done?

Comment: That is a more complex query than you may think.  If you are doing this often you may find it easier to separate the date from the time or just save the date and don't give a time and you will always get the 00:00:00 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following query

```
UPDATE <table> SET <date column>= DATE(<date column>);
```

E.g.

```
UPDATE Customer SET startDate = DATE(startDate);
```

You can do it from the console using the `mysql` tool.

Answer (score 0):

See [Update multiple records simultaneously with ActiveRecord in Rails using one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455479/update-multiple-records-simultaneously-with-activerecord-in-rails-using-one-query)

Comment: How can I use update all without overwriting the date (2011-04-12)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to alter multiple *records* rather than columns. Anyway:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET dato = DATE_FORMAT(dato, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Should I do this in the console/terminal?

Comment: If this is one-time alteration, just fire up mysql console and do it there. If you need to do this regularly, then you should reconsider fixing your application code. BTW, I'd recommend Jonas' solution instead of mine.